# Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: geometry, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Is there any relationship between BSD conjecture and Fermat's Last Theorem? What is the importance of the analytic degree of the L-function of an elliptic curve stated in the BSD conjecture in Fermat's Last tHeorem?

Comment: There are lots of connections. For example, Kolyvagin (essentially) proved rank part of the BSD for rank $1$ for modular elliptic curves. Of course, apres W/TW/BCDT (the things necessary to prove Fermat's last theorem) this is a statement about all elliptic curves.